# Navbar not expanding when running example on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

While working through a web dev course, I got to a portion on learning BootStrap.  I have a Navbar added to my page, directly copied from the example given here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

While all of the Navbar components are loading in, and all of the buttons are functioning, the Navbar will not expand.  I am running a Node server on my local machine, and requesting an HTML page which correctly renders, except for the menu not expanding.

Here is my HTML page with the Navbar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><%= typeof name !== "undefined" ? name : "Error" %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="Boilerplate HTML Page">
    
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
</head>



<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Express Demo</a>
            <button onclick="" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" 
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/rand" >Random</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/r/chickens">Chickens</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/r/soccer">Soccer</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/r/mightyharvest">MightyHarvest</a>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <h1>Browsing r/<%= typeof name !== "undefined" ? name : "Error"%></h1>
    <h2><%= description %></h2>
    <p>Sub count: <%= subscribers %></p>
    
    <hr>
    
    <% for(let post of posts) { %>
        <article>
            <p><%=post.title%> - <b><%= post.author %></b></p>
            <% if (post.img) { %>
                <img src="<%= post.img %>" alt="">
            <% } %>
        </article>
    <% } %>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried the most up to date links offering the Bootstrap and jQuery versions, but the problem persists. As mentioned, the code for the Navbar are identical to the example code, save for changing the button text and href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your source and omitted the jquery. I used CDNs for the Bootstrap CSS and JS and the menu expands (assuming the window is small enough).

Try swapping

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

for

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Might have to use a CDN for the CSS as well.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I had tried several other CDN links that hadn't helped lol